# meaning of the phrase "great move" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/boxing/45706394). Here is the context:

> Fury beat Wladimir Klitschko in November 2015 to become the lineal champion and remains undefeated after 27 fights, while Wilder has won all 40 of his fights - 39 by knockout.
>   "It's a dare to be **great move**," Fury added. "Two fights, 10 fights - it doesn't really matter. I can't lose this fight.

What does he mean by *great move* and why an article is omitted before the phrase?

Comment: a **move** is a (tactical) decision or action taken in any context where strategy is involved —chess and other board-games,  football, wrestling, politics, or even on a date. In AmE it can be used sarcastically. Let's say a buddy spills beer or coffee in his lap because he's not being careful with his elbows on the table. You could say, "Nice move, dude." You could say the same if he makes a pass on your girlfriend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The journalist has not correctly punctuated the phrase. It should be hyphenated, like this:

> It's a **dare-to-be-great** move

The fighter is saying that, by doing this move (that is, by accepting the challenge from a tough opponent), he is daring to be great.

The missing article is there, just before the *dare-to-be-great* adjectival phrase.

Interestingly enough, I found this same phrase (correctly punctuated) in another [sports article](http://www.basketballinsiders.com/nba-rumors-david-blatt-next-coach-of-cavs-cavaliers-cleveland-head/):

> This would be an excellent hire for the Cavaliers, as Blatt is considered one of the best basketball coaches outside of the NBA. The term “genius” often gets thrown around when describing Blatt, and it’s **a dare-to-be-great move** that could really pay off for Cleveland.